# CSS – Strech UL from top to bottom of browser

Tags: css, wordpress, layout, wordpress-theming, html

I'm trying to reorganize the backend of my Wordpress install. Too much code to actually paste here, but visit here:

*Actual link removed*/wp-admin/

What I'm trying to do is to stretch the menu to the left, so it goes all the way from the top to the bottom of the browser, and also move down "Log out" to the very bottom of the browser.

Don't know how to solve this..

Comment: @Remy Must've been something temporary, works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make the container have position absolute, the  itself should be position: fixed with 100% height
To push the log out button down it can have position absolute and a bottom value of 0.

CSS should be similar to the below:

```
#adminmenuwrap {
    position: absolute;
}

#adminmenu {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
}

li.log-out {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```